# assignment operator with maps

Tags: c++

```
map<char *, int> sym_addr;
map<char *, int> sym_tbl;
void set_map(map<char *, int> & sym_tbl)
{
 sym_addr = sym_tbl;
}
```

Is there any problem with the above assignment?

Comment: Problem: The keys of `sym_addr` may be leaked. But perhaps it's not what you're asking.

Comment: Please define "any problem" more specifically.

Comment: I want to copy contents of a map into another map. If this is wrong, then what is the right way to do that?

Comment: As far as I can see, you can find anything in those maps at all if you also have those char pointers stored elsewhere (because you can only look up addresses of strings). So the maps are not the owners of the keys and the assignment should be fine.

Comment: Can you guarantee that whatever the char* points to is valid for the lifetime of the maps? If not you might be better off changing the map to std::map<std::string, int>

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to change the keys to `std::string` : `std::map< std::string, int>`

If you want to copy, pass that object by const reference:

```
typedef std::map< std::string, int> myMapType;
myMapType sym_addr;
myMapType sym_tbl;
void set_map(const myMapType & sym_tbl)
{
 sym_addr = sym_tbl;
}
```

Other then that, there are no problems. map::operator= is used to copy the content of one map into another.

Comment: I might recommend `typedef std::map<std::string, int> symtable;` to simplify the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the argument by `const` reference, otherwise you prevent copying a map declared `const`.

Also, make sure you understand exactly what happens if you use `char*` as a key - the key is the *address* of the string, not its contents. If you want to index the map by string *values*, use `std::string` as the key.